# What am I doing wrong here? Showing $\text{Ord}_{N}(a)|k\iff a^k\equiv 1 \pmod N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Show $\text{Ord}_{N}(a)|k\iff a^k\equiv 1 \pmod N$ where $a$ is invertible.

What I did is: If  $\text{Ord}_{N}(a)|k$ it is obvious. Suppose $a^k\equiv 1 \pmod N$. Not let us assume by contradiction that $\text{Ord}_{N}(a):=d$ doesn't divide $k$. Since by definition $k\ge d$ (Here $k>d$), then $k=m\cdot d+t$ where $0<t<d$ for some $m\in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Therefore: $a^k=a^{md+t}=a^{md}a^t=a^t=1 \pmod N$. But since $t<d$, that is a contradiction to the fact that $d$ is the order, i.e the smallest to satisfy $a^n\equiv 1 \pmod N$.

I feel like it can't be that easy, and that there must be some step I have been remiss in taking. Moreover, I haven't used the fact that $a$ is invertible which only supports my insecurity about it. I would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: It is that easy, and the invertibility of $a$ is needed so that $\operatorname{Ord}_N(a)$ is defined, it doesn't enter in the way the proof proceeds.

Comment: Oh I see. I am not used to that kind of questions in final exams so it got me wondering. Thank you for your approval. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in the hypotheses, you forgot $a$ coprime to $N$.

Another proof:

The order of $a$ modulo $N$ is the positive generator of $\ker f$, where $f$ is the group homomorphism:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf Z&\to \bigl(\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z\bigr)^\times\\
n&\mapsto a^n
\end{align*}
Now $\;\operatorname{ord}a\mid k\iff a\in \ker f\iff a^k\equiv 1\mod N. $

Comment: We weren't referring Group Theory in Number Theory class but as someone who took Group Theory before, that is a really creative solution. :)